# sqlalchemy foreign composite key (declarative)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've seen a bunch of questions bounce around the issue but I can't quite get things correct.

I'm failing to generate my tables, here are the snipped versions.

```
class Member(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "members"
    discord_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    guild = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('guilds.discord_id'),primary_key=True)
    rs_runs = relationship("RSRun",secondary='member_on_rs_run')
    # guild = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('guilds.discord_id'),primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("discord_id","guild"),)

class Guild(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "guilds"
    name = Column(String)
    discord_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

class RSRun(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "rs_runs"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    creator = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('members.discord_id'))
    members = relationship("Member",secondary='member_on_rs_run')
    guild = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("guilds.discord_id"),nullable=False)


class MemberOnRSRun(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "member_on_rs_run"
    member_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key = True)
    member_guild = Column(BigInteger,primary_key=True)
    run_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('rs_runs.id'),primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(['member_id', 'member_guild'],[Member.discord_id, Member.guild]),)
```

I run into the error
psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "members"

However I have a Unique constraint for those keys together, and I have a composite ForeignKeyConstraint properly generated (I think).  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The MembersOnRSRun table is for doing a Many to Many relationship.

Note, everything was working fine until I added the Guilds table with the guilds columns.

Comment: I wonder if I need to do the PrimaryKey constraint differently?

Comment: It's caused by `creator = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('members.discord_id'))` in `RSRun`. `members.discord_id` is not a key by itself, it is a part of the composite primary key and of the (redundant) composite unique constraint. Did you mean for `RSRun.guild` to reference `Member` as well instead of `Guild`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä hey thanks!  That sounds right. How would I reference the composite key?  And while I think they will probably always be the same, I wanted it to reference just the guild table.

Comment: Ah so I probably have to include both parts and then do a foreignkeyconstraint. I’ll try that

Comment: @IljaEverilä that was the problem, if you would like to submit an answer I'll approve it.  Thank you for your assistance